# What package supports pause of sqlite query result for NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I need to process huge table that is stored in SQLite. And processing requires writing data back to SQLite database. It seams that `sqlite3` npm package that I'm currently using do not allow to pause fetching of rows that leads to out of memory.

Is there any library that allows pause query result fetching?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean [this](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3) module ? If yes, i guess you are looking for [each](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databaseeachsql-param--callback-complete), or even better [this](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#statementeachparam--callback-complete)